# Divide Query Into Two Random Groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on an AB test and need to divide a population. How should I divide something like
`User.where(:condition => true)` randomly into two roughly equal groups?

I'm considering iterating through the whole array and pushing onto one of two other arrays based on a random value, but this is a large query and that sounds very slow.

e.g.

```
array.each do |object|
  if rand(2) == 0
    first_group << object
  else
    second_group << object
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a random ordering right from the database you can do

```
# MySQL
User.order('RAND()')

# PostgreSQL
User.order('RANDOM()')
```

A nice one liner to split an array into two halves can be found [here](http://heyrod.com/snippet/s/split-ruby-array-in-half.html):

```
left, right = a.each_slice( (a.size/2.0).round ).to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a definition which would return the following

```
def randomizer(sample_size)
    initial_arr = ["objq","obj2", "objn"]
    sampler = initial_arr(sample_size)
    sampled_data = initial_arr - sampler  
end
```

here sample_size will be size of the array would like to randomize and split like 50 or 100 based on your data size.

for basic trial I have done the same as

```
[:foo, :bar, :hello, :world, :ruby].sample(3)
```

output would be [:hello, :ruby, :bar].

second would be the result of  `[:foo, :bar, :hello, :world, :ruby] - [:foo, :bar, :hello, :world, :ruby].sample(3)` which is `[:hello, :world]`

This way you can avoid looping over array and execute the code faster.

for additional information you can check http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sample

This is available in ruby 1.9.1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform basic [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html) operations on the query result:

```
results = User.where(:condition => true)
```

Start by using `shuffle` to put the array to get a random ordering:

```
array = results.shuffle
```

Then `slice` the array in to roughly equal parts:

```
group1 = array.slice(0..array.length/2)
group2 = array.slice(array.length/2+1..array.length)
```

If order is important, `sort` the groups back into the initial order:

```
group1.sort! {|a, b| results.index(a) <=> results.index(b) }
group2.sort! {|a, b| results.index(a) <=> results.index(b) }
```